# Kurento example error

Tags: java, webrtc, kurento

I am trying the tutorial of kureno with 
http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-1-helloworld.html

I follow the steps as in this example,like bellow

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world
git checkout 6.2.1
mvn compile exec:java
```

It is compiled and the web page is loaded,and local streaming is showing.when it started with remote stream.this shows an error in console.

> Error message from server: [KurentoClient]  Timeout of 10000
>   milliseconds waiting from response to request
>   {"id":1133856,"method":"create","params":{"type":"MediaPipeline","constructorParams":{}},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}

Comment: Is the kurento media server process running?  if not, run:  sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start

Comment: @mtbikemike kurento server is already running

Comment: The socket connection is disconnecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this command `$netstat -ltnp`, you know kurento-server-6 is running or not. If yes, you get this

tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      -

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world
git checkout 6.2.1
mvn compile exec:java
```

are you behind any proxy or network? I tried this example, It works for me.